# C#: Issues to return a generic list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code:

Model:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyAplication.Models
{
  public class Result
  {
    public string MarketName { get; set; }
    public double High { get; set; }
    public double Low { get; set; }
    public double Volume { get; set; }
    public double Last { get; set; }
    public double BaseVolume { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public double Bid { get; set; }
    public double Ask { get; set; }
    public int OpenBuyOrders { get; set; }
    public int OpenSellOrders { get; set; }
    public double PrevDay { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
  }

  public class RootInfoCoins
  {
      public bool success { get; set; }
      public string message { get; set; }        
      public List<Result> result { get; set; }        
  }
}
```

And this class:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using PeekAndGoApp.Models;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Net.Http.Headers;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using System.Collections;

    namespace MyAplication.Controllers
    {
        [Produces("application/json")]
        [Route("api/[controller]")]
        [ApiController]
        public class CoinsController : ControllerBase
        {
            [HttpGet]
            public async Task<IEnumerable<RootInfoCoins>> Get()
            {
                string Baseurl = "https://bittrex.com";
                string Parameters = "api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries";
                RootInfoCoins CoinsInfo = new RootInfoCoins();                  

                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    //Passing service base url  
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                    //Define request data format  
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    //Sending request to find web api REST service resource GetAllCoins using HttpClient  
                    HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync(Parameters);

                    //Checking the response is successful or not which is sent using HttpClient  
                    if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        //Storing the response details recieved from web api   
                        string CoinResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;                                               
                        CoinsInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootInfoCoins>(CoinResponse);
                    }
                    return CoinsInfo.result;                        
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem is that i try to return my data and get this:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

I'm new in C# (i'm learning). I've done a lot of research and i can't resolve my problem. Maybe I'm not understanding the concepts of this language. Please, can someone help me?

PS: I have attached an image so that you can see "the format" of the data I am receiving. [image: Debugging]

Thanks a lot.

Jhon.

Comment: You are not converting to the same type, One is `List<Models.Result>` and the other one is `IEnumerable<Models.RootInfoCoins>`

Comment: You've got a method expected to return a *set* of `RootInfoCoins` objects and instead you're trying to give it a set of `Result` objects (that you obtained from a single instance of a `RootInfoCoins`. Not sure what you need to change but there's something logically amiss here.

Comment: `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable` @styx, The problem is the casting.

Comment: @Nekeniehl yea alread fixed my answer, (which is now basicly as same yours)

Comment: Please Update the CoinResponse string

Comment: On a side note this line `res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result` would cause a deadlock because you are mixing `async/await` with `.Result`. Instead change it to `await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`. As a rule of thumb if you are using `async/await` then use it throughout the whole call stack.

Comment: I think your response in List<Result>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Result>> Get()
    {
        string Baseurl = "https://bittrex.com";
        string Parameters = "api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries";
        RootInfoCoins CoinsInfo = new RootInfoCoins();

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //Passing service base url  
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("");

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            //Define request data format  
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            //Sending request to find web api REST service resource GetAllCoins using HttpClient  
            HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync(Parameters);

            //Checking the response is successful or not which is sent using HttpClient  
            if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //Storing the response details recieved from web api   
                string CoinResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                CoinsInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootInfoCoins>(CoinResponse);
            }

            return CoinsInfo.result;

        }
```

change this because CoinsInfo.result is a List type so, you change  the return type

```
  public async Task<IEnumerable<Result>> Get()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. With your explanation i resolved my problem. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

`Get()` expects to return `IEnumerable<RootInfoCoins>`, but you are trying to return `List<Result>`. You can either return the `RootInfoCoins` created from `JsonConvert` by changing the signature and `return` statement to

```
public async Task<RootInfoCoins> Get()
{
    //...
    return coinsInfo;
}
```

Or return `List<Result>` by changing the signature to

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Result>> Get() { }
```